# In Emacs how do I edit multiple points at once?

Tags: emacs, elisp

There's two variations. I think you can select a rectangle and add stuff to the beginning and end of all lines.

I'd also like to know if it's possible to select multiple points that are on different offsets to where you edit all the points at once. I think Yasnippet provides something similar, but only when you use a predefined template. Something like this.

```
<div class="">
<a class="">
```

where i can mark a point on both class things and typing will edit both class attributes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Emacs Rocks! describes [mark-multiple](https://github.com/magnars/mark-multiple.el), which does what you want.  (Here's their [video introduction](http://emacsrocks.com/e08.html).)

**EDIT:** @Lifton points out it has been superceded by [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el).

Comment: Note that this has since been superseded by [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) (which looks like it's still in development).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Juancho's answer, I've used Steve Yegge's [`multi-select`](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyemacsutils/multi-select-el) for your purpose. Example usage (the first example will provide what I think you want):

```
 C-u C-M-m w foo <RET> <RET>
  - inserts/prepends "foo" to every multi-selection (you can also append or replace text)

 C-u -1 C-M-m r <pre>\(\w+\).+\s-+\(.+\)</pre>
  - selects first and last word of the contents every <pre> tag
    (provided the contents don't span multiple lines)

 C-M-m x M-x upcase-region
  - converts all multi-selections in buffer to uppercase

 C-u M-w C-q C-j --- C-q C-j <RET>
  - saves all multi-selections to kill-ring as a single item,
    with selections separated by "---" on a line by itself
```